# Clearing Magento sessions folder via SSH because of Inode space - Linux. & Cron Job

Tags: cron, session

Just wanted some clarification on a question I previously asked.

I'm going to clear my Magento's session folder (.../var/session/).

How many days should I clear it prior to? If I cleared the sessions folder entirely, would it break my Magento store?

Or should I allow around 7 days of session folder lee-way?

I'd be using this code via SSH:

find /public_html/var/session/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

or

sudo rm -rf /public_html/var/session/

========================================================

As well as this, I dont believe there is a cron-job set up to automatically remove session folder contents, being as the inode space is at 98% because of it. Can anyone point me to a good guide or let me know how I would go about setting one up? Or at least a way to see why it hasnt run, if it has been set up that is

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the entire folder you will "Kickout" all active users. The only other effect it will have on old users is they would not be able to login to their old active session. I doubt that you have sessions that last for 7 days (You most likely have Cookies that last that long)

A long term solution is to setup a php garbage collector to remove you expired session files.